# Ports closed after EJBCA (JEE application) deployment

Tags: azure, networking, wildfly, firewall, ejbca

I just finished deploying ejbca 6 on debian9 azure VM using this tutorial :

https://wiki.e-odyssey.net/ejbca/french-tuto

The installation succeeds, however : the ports  443,80 were closed

root@ejbcaDebian9:/home/ejbca# nmap <ejbca_public_ip>

```
Starting Nmap 7.40 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-07-01 16:43 UTC
Nmap scan report for my_ip
Host is up (0.0013s latency).
Not shown: 995 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
80/tcp   closed http
443/tcp  closed https
8080/tcp open   http-proxy
8443/tcp open   https-alt
```

tryed opening them with ufw and by adding networking inbound rules on azure
But it didn't work so i rebooted the VM

after a reboot however :
no port is open anymore

pki@ejbcaDebian9:~$ netstat -lapunta
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1001 but you should be root.)
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0     36 172.18.0.4:22           51.144.166.96:37858     ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           -

```
pki@ejbcaDebian9~$ ps -aux | grep jboss
pki        716  0.0  0.0  11112   928 pts/0    S+   17:04   0:00 grep jboss
pki@ejbcaDebian9~$ ps -aux | grep wildfly
pki        723  0.0  0.0  11112   996 pts/0    S+   17:05   0:00 grep wildfly
```

and in the wildfly log we have this :

```
2021-07-01 16:22:43,402 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-1) WELD-000900: 2.3.5 (Final)

2021-07-01 16:22:44,737 INFO  [org.cesecore.config.ConfigurationHolder] (MSC service thread 1-3) Allow external re-configuration: false

2021-07-01 16:22:44,737 DEBUG [org.cesecore.config.ConfigurationHolder] (MSC service thread 1-3) Add resource to configuration: /conf/cesecore.properties

2021-07-01 16:22:44,758 DEBUG [org.cesecore.config.ConfigurationHolder] (MSC service thread 1-3) Added url to configuration source: vfs:/content/ejbca.ear/lib/ejbca-properties.jar/conf/cesecore.properties

root@ejbcaDebian9 /opt/wildfly/standalone/log# tail -f server.log
2021-07-01 16:44:22,523 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0008: Undertow HTTPS listener httpspub suspending

2021-07-01 16:44:22,523 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0007: Undertow HTTPS listener httpspub stopped, was bound to 0.0.0.0:8442

2021-07-01 16:44:22,523 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0008: Undertow HTTP listener http suspending

2021-07-01 16:44:22,524 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0007: Undertow HTTP listener http stopped, was bound to 0.0.0.0:8080
2021-07-01 16:44:22,537 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0208: Stopped subdeployment (runtime-name: ra-gui.war) in 311ms
2021-07-01 16:44:22,538 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0004: Undertow 1.4.0.Final stopping

2021-07-01 16:44:22,545 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0208: Stopped subdeployment (runtime-name: doc.war) in 319ms

2021-07-01 16:44:22,551 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0208: Stopped subdeployment (runtime-name: adminweb.war) in 340ms

2021-07-01 16:44:22,564 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment ejbca.ear (runtime-name: ejbca.ear) in 352ms

2021-07-01 16:44:22,567 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0050: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) stopped in 280ms
```

systemctl status wildfly doesn't work. Seems like this type of ejbca setup does't enable me to restart ejbca or wildfly services.

Iam wondering if it's not a persistance problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Your log tells me that WildFly was shut down. If you look further up in the logfile you should see some reason for the shutdown (unless you pressed ctrl-c).
The guide you are following is rather old though, using a since long outdated version of EJBCA. I would suggest using the latest release of EJBCA instead from https://www.ejbca.org/

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Yes i reboot the VM 
I just don't understand why i get closed ports after install completes. 
I tryed differents  linux distributions , ejbca, wildfly versions. 
Is ejbca compatible with azure VMs? 
i have opened ejbca ports on the azure networking /firewall and also opened ports via ufw on the VM itself.

Comment: "systemctl restart wildfly" doesn't work here. Is it linked to ejbca 6 ?

Comment: Yes, EJBCA is compatible with Azure. You can find EJBCA in Azure Marketplace. Perhaps it's a good idea to start a free Azure EJBCA Enterprise trial, then you can look at the configuration there. You can find the link to Azure from ejbca.org. https://www.ejbca.org/download/

Comment: Ok, i'll do it. In the mean time i was able to do the quick install for ejbca 7 on my personnal virtualbox VM. 
And it worked fine (appart from the fact my p12 password was not recognized ) but it worked for the public part.
then i just rebooted my VM and now nothing works. 
How can i reload wildfly service in the quick install because i don't see wildfly running.
In the normal install i was able to reload the service easily

Comment: I believe it's not installed as a service in the quick install. To start you change to the wildfly directory and run with bin/standalone.sh.

Comment: I finally was able to make it work.  But i had to manually insert in the database the superadmin password and hashed password and status.